# copy entire drive folder (including sub folders) contents to gcs

Tags: airflow, drive

I've had success using GoogleDriveToGCSOperator to copy a file from drive to gcs.
But what I really need to do is, given drive folder id then copy all files and subdirectories of that drive folder to gcs.

Is there an operator that does this using airflow?
I've googled and googled and had no success. I'm assuming there's some solution for this as I'm sure I'm not the only one needing this.

I've had success doing this with colab notebook but am now hoping to schedule something in airflow to achieve same task. Not sure if mount drive and pyDrive facilities in Colab are directly transferrable to airflow, or whether there's a better airflow solve for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is no operator to do copy the whole gdrive folder to GCS, but you can develop a new one.

If you read the official operator [GoogleDriveToGCSOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/gdrive_to_gcs.py#L28) source code, you can see that use `GoogleDriveHook` to download the file frome gdrive, and `GCSHook` to create a new file in GCS.
So you need to list the files in gdrive, and copy them in a loop.
The problem is that you cannot list the files in gdrive using `GoogleDriveHook`, so you have to call the google API do list the file. [Here](https://github.com/googleworkspace/python-samples/blob/main/drive/snippets/drive-v3/file_snippet/search_file.py) you can find an example.
Once you have the files list, you can create a new operator by modifying the `GoogleDriveToGCSOperator` [execute method](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/gdrive_to_gcs.py#L89-L106) (and for sure the `__init__` method arguments based on your needs):

```py
    def execute(self, context: 'Context'):
        files_list = ... # read for the API
        gdrive_hook = GoogleDriveHook(
            gcp_conn_id=self.gcp_conn_id,
            delegate_to=self.delegate_to,
            impersonation_chain=self.impersonation_chain,
        )
        gcs_hook = GCSHook(
            gcp_conn_id=self.gcp_conn_id,
            delegate_to=self.delegate_to,
            impersonation_chain=self.impersonation_chain,
        )
        for file_name in files_list:
            ... # get the gdrive file name without prefix
            ... # choose a prefix for GCS objects
            file_metadata = gdrive_hook.get_file_id(
                folder_id=self.folder_id, file_name=file_name, drive_id=self.drive_id
            )
            with gcs_hook.provide_file_and_upload(
                bucket_name=self.bucket_name, object_name=<GCS prefix>/<gdrive file name without prefix>
            ) as file:
                gdrive_hook.download_file(file_id=file_metadata["id"], file_handle=file)
```